# Finding a special power series

Tags: power-series

Find a power series for F, such that $F'(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Don't understand how to come up with the solution

Comment: Do you know the power series for $e^x$, and if so, do you know how to get the power series for $e^{-x^2}$ from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the power series for $e^x$ is 
$$
\sum_{n=0} ^\infty { \frac{x^n}{n!} } .
$$
Thus, the power series for $e^{-x^2}$ is 
$$
\sum_{n=0} ^\infty { \frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!} } = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty { \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!} }  .
$$
Integrating term by term yields
$$
F(x) = \int F'(x) = \int \sum_{n=0} ^\infty { \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!} } = \sum_{n=0} ^\infty { \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n + 1}}{(2n+1)n!} } .
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$F'(x)=e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$$
with radius of convergence $+\infty$ hence by integrating term by term we find:

$$\int_0^xF'(t)dt=F(x)-F(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

The power series for $F'(X)$ is $$F'(x) = \sum_0^\infty \frac{(-x)^{2n}}{n!} = \sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}$$
We now integrate each side and get:
$$
\begin{align}
F(X) &= \sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (x)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(n!)}
\end{align}$$